# Do Indexes in the T-SQL Data Warehouse automatically go over and optimize into the SSAS Cube?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, performance, data-warehouse, ssas, performance-tuning

Do Indexes in the T-SQL Data Warehouse automatically go over and optimize into the SSAS Cube?
I am reading that applying indexes, will transfer into SSAS. I thought SQL and SSAS are totally different environments.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/acda0b00-b40c-47cf-b9ca-334ccf2e4212/how-indexing-affect-performance-on-analyses-service-cube?forum=sqlanalysisservices

> So the point is, create appropriate indexes on source tables to
>   improve the performance of the query which SSAS fires while processing
>   the cube or while retrieving data from the source. If you have access
>   to the source data, you can use this DMV to identify missing indexes
>   or you can use the Index Tuning Advisor for identifying and creating
>   missing indexes on the source.

Additionally, do columnstore indexes translate into SSAS Cubes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you quoted is worded a bit confusing but it says that it improves the performance of *processing* the cube, not querying it.

> So the point is, create appropriate indexes on source tables to
>   improve the **performance of the query which SSAS fires while processing
>   the cube or while retrieving data from the source.** If you have access
>   to the source data, you can use this DMV to identify missing indexes
>   or you can use the Index Tuning Advisor for identifying and creating
>   missing indexes on the source.

Querying the cube doesn't *retrieve data from the source*, it retrieves data from the SSAS storage engine.

What can happen however is that your cube has a drillthrough action that action may read from the actual source database and filter your fact table on the dimension keys which were filtering the measure in the cube, in which case it may benefit from indexes in your data warehouse.